# Not Able To Connect to Windows Server 2008 R2 using FileZilla Externally

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, iis-7.5

I configured FTP Service/Role on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.  I am able to connect from the inside, but not from the outside.  On the inside I tested using cmd prompt and IE FTP.  On the outside, I am testing with FileZilla and IE FTP.  From the outside, IE FTP prompts me to enter my username/pwd, but nothing happens.  Page eventually times out and I get "Internet Explorer cannot display page".  Using FileZilla, I get the following messages.  Note FileZilla resolved domain name and authenticates.  I did not configure FTP Wirewall Support on the FTP site.  I am not sure if I need to do this.  I set up basic authentication, non-ssl, not allowing anonymous.  I testing with Windows Firewall Turned off and on (I added windows firewall rule for port 21).  On my network firewall (Cisco), I added a rule to forward port 21 traffic to FTP Server.

Status: Resolving address of ftp.technologyblends.com
Status: Connecting to 75.149.66.201:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER ***

Response:   331 Password required for ***.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 Windows_NT
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Response:    LANG EN*
Response:    UTF8
Response:    AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT C;P;
Response:    CCC
Response:    HOST
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:   211 END
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your connection to ACTIVE MODE instead of PASV

Comment: Nothing seems to work.  At this point I am not sure if its on my Network Firewall or something on my FTP Server.  While inside the network FTP is working as expected.  I just cannot get it to work from the outside.  Not sure how to troubleshoot where the problem may be.  Thanks for any tips.

Comment: just for your consideration and this only as a comparative scenario, have you considered installing filezilla server instead of using MS ftp?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have NAT going on and the server has a private address. The most likely cause is you not letting the ephemeral ports through. I think that if you just made a DMZ and let everything through, it would start working. But that's insecure. The better way is to find a way to limit the range of passive ports used and forward that range to your server. Here are some instructions: https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2334/How-to-Configure-Passive-Port-Range-for-the-FTP-Service-in-IIS.html . Then forward that same range on the NATing router to the internal IP of your server. The tutorial linked shows 6001-6001, but I recommend that you do something like 60000-61000. The reason being that the "lower" numbers in the thousands get used by other traffic a lot whereas the higher ones tend to remain quiet.

That said, the FTP shim in the NAT should create that port mapping automatically as a RELATED connection. Check if you don't have them blocked in the firewall and if the FTP shim is even loaded. On Linux, it could be called `ip_conntrack`, `nf_conntrack`, `nf_conntrack_ftp` or `nf_conntrack_proto_ftp` depending on the version. It may be even compiled monolithically in which case you won't see it among the modules, but it will still work.